# extjs3 itemselector event not fired

Tags: extjs4

I tested all operations, add, remove, click etc..  only the `change` event fired in listener :(
and this occurred while I removed items in toField,
I really want to fire event while add item to toField (just double click fromField item).

How do I to capture this event?

Thanks.

```js
var documentSelector = Ext.create('Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector', {
    name: 'documentSelector',
    fieldLabel: 'Document',
    anchor: '100%',
    store: a,
    valueField: "name",
    displayField: "name",
    allowBlank: false,
    msgTarget: 'side',
    listeners: {
        added: function(obj, event) {
            console.log("added");
        },
        change: function(obj, event) {
            console.log("change");
        },
        removed: function(obj, event) {
            console.log("removed");
        },
        blur: function(obj, event) {
            console.log("blur");
        },
        click: function(obj) {
            console.log('click');
        },
        select: function(obj) {
            console.log('select');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the events `blur` and `click` will never fire because they are not an event on the `itemSelector`. 
ItemSelector's events are documented [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector) for [extjs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/)(4.07).

You can just use the change event and act based on **change** event.

            `/**
             * @event change
             * Fires when a user-initiated change is detected in the value of the field.
             * @param {Ext.form.field.Field} this
             * @param {Object} newValue The new value
             * @param {Object} oldValue The original value
             */`
Add a handler to change event based on the **newValue** or compare **newValue** to **oldValue**